# How to bound values to jList indices

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I'm making my first GUI app needed for my workplace. I want to calculate some values, some from radio buttons, some from user inputs.

I also want to add to the final result some other options (there are extraoptions for a mobile telephony company that costs).

Regarding the large number of EO(extraoptions), I want to let the user select multiple choices.

I tried a comboBox but it only allow you to select one option so I though about a list (maybe jList?)

Every EO needs to have it's generic name but it's very important to hold a value (key) to be calculated into the final result.

So the question is: What do you think it's the best way to do it, and how? (and not the hardest because I'm quite a begginer, please)

Thanks in advance, and don't be harsh with me, it's my first question!
the app: http://tinypic.com/r/wugsnm/5

**UPDATE:**
So I managed to take some steps further into completing this app.
So far I was able to take the selected row from the list and take it into the total result.
**BUT:** a)It doesn't allow me anymore to calculate the result without selecting something from the list. (just the text fields)
b)It doesn't update the result. If I select another row, the result stay the same
The code looks like this:

```
public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {
Double radioNumb1 = null, radioNumb2 = null, subsidyNumb , result = null, radioNumb3 = null, radioNumb4 = null, periodNumb, ans ;

String[] eo_names = {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5"}; //the names of EO (for now)
double[] eo_values = {10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000}; // the values of EO (for now)    
NumberFormat nfRegular = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US); // to shorten the decimals of the result

public void greaterCondition (Double radioNumb){
        result = ((subsidyNumb + ans)/radioNumb) * periodNumb;
     if (periodNumb > radioNumb){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Perioada contractuala dorita este mai mare decat cea initiala", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }}
private void initRadioButton() { //setting the second radioButton as default
    radioButton1.setSelected(false);
    radioButton2.setSelected(true);
    radioButton3.setSelected(false);
    radioButton4.setSelected(false);
}

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        init();

    }

private void init(){
    setTitle("CED calculator for KA");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
   private void equalButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        radioNumb1 = Double.parseDouble(radioButton1.getText());
        radioNumb2 = Double.parseDouble(radioButton2.getText());
        radioNumb3 = Double.parseDouble(radioButton3.getText());
        radioNumb4 = Double.parseDouble(radioButton4.getText());
        subsidyNumb = Double.parseDouble(subsidyField.getText());
        periodNumb = Double.parseDouble(periodField.getText());

        for (int i : jList1.getSelectedIndices()){
            ans = eo_values[i];

        }
         jList1 = new JList<String>(eo_names);


        if (radioButton1.isSelected()){
            greaterCondition(radioNumb1);
        }
        else if (radioButton2.isSelected()){
            greaterCondition(radioNumb2);
        }
        else if (radioButton3.isSelected()){
            greaterCondition(radioNumb3);
        }
        else if (radioButton4.isSelected()){
            greaterCondition(radioNumb4);
        }



        answerLabel.setText("" + nfRegular.format(result) + " euro");

    }
```

What do you think that can be done? This is how far I went.

Comment: Indeed, I think a jList is the way to go. Just as a quick reference, check the java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: I already turned the internet upside down searching for the answer and asking a direct questions was my last chance. All I found are lists that handle Strings, not integers. And thanks for the edit:)

Comment: Check my answer... it may help you.

Comment: Simply store the ExtraOptions in the list and write a custom renderer for showing them. getSelectedValue will directly return the item you are interested in.

Comment: I updated the code, please take a look and maybe you can help me with an opinion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JList` objects are built to handle tasks like the one you are facing.

Addressing your comment, they handle `String` entries, indeed. The entries are stored in an array, and, as such, you can make reference to each entry by its position in the array.

Let me illustrate my point (taken from [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)).

You can build your JList like this:

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
JList<String> myList = new JList<String>(data);
```

This will create a `JList` object that holds four strings (notice that you are specifying that this JList will hold strings when you write `<String>`. Further reference: [Java Tutorials: Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)).

When you select an item from your list, you can retrieve it's position using `getSelectedIndex()`, which returns *the smallest selected cell index or the selection when only a single item is selected in the list*.

So, let's say you select the entry `"three"` in your JList:

```
myList.getSelectedIndex(); // Will return 2 (remember arrays are "zero based")
```

If you select more than one entry in your list, the `getSelectedIndices()` will return *an array of all of the selected indices, in increasing order.*

So, let's say you select the entries `"one"` and `"three"`:

```
myList.getSelectedIndices(); // Will return an array with the values [0, 2]
```

So, addressing to your specific situation, I would create an array of strings to hold your "EO" values, and use an array to "map" each selection to the relevant value you need.

Since you are not posting any specific data about what you are trying to do, I'll write a simple example

```
 String[] eo_names = {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5"};
 double[] eo_values = {3, 5, 8, 12, 1};
 JList<String> eoList = new JList<String>(eo_names);
```

Now, let's create a little method that returns the sum of each selected value:

```
 public double sumSelectedValues() {
     double ans = 0;
     for(int i : eoList.getSelectedIndices()) {
         ans += eo_values[i];
     }
     return ans;
 }
```

Now, let's create a simple method to print the selected values (Strings):

```
 public void printSelectedValues() {
     // getSelectedValueList() replaces getSelectedValues() starting with JDK 1.7
     for(String s : eoList.getSelectedValueList()) {
         System.out.println(s);
     }
 }
```

---

Let's take this one step further.

I'm assuming that you have an "EO" list that has a tag and a value; in other words, "EO's" are pairs of key-value attributes. You can handle this kind of stuff with a map.

Let's say your EO key-value pairs are as follows:

```
EO   | Value
-----+------
Val1 | 3
Val2 | 5
Val3 | 8
Val4 | 12
Val5 | 1
```

Let's create a `HashMap` with this data:

```
HashMap<String,Double> myEoMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
myEoMap.put("Val1",3);
myEoMap.put("Val2",5);
myEoMap.put("Val3",8);
myEoMap.put("Val4",12);
myEoMap.put("Val5",1);
```

Notice that the "key" (the first argument of the `put` method) must be unique.

Now, let's create a JList with the key values:

```
String[] k = new String[myEoMap.size()];
JList<String> myEoList = new JList<String>(myEoMap.keySet().toArray(k));
```

And now, let's write a little method to print the values selected in your list:

```
public void printSelectedValues() {
    for(String s : myEoList.getSelectedValueList()) {
        if(myEoMap.containsKey(s)) {
            System.out.println("Key " + s + " found! The value is: " + myEoMap.get(s));
        } else {
            System.err.println("Oops, no value found");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: outch, that's brittle ;-) Instead of a weakly mapping strings to values simply store the values (and write a custom renderer for showing them), getSelectedValue will directly return the item you are interested in.

Comment: I'll check both answers. Nevertheless, thanks a lot Barranka for your time and help. I clearly understand more now. As for the renderer, I never used it but I will try to find some examples on the net.

Comment: @kleopatra unless the value in the list is not what it is intended, but just a tag. I know this solution is a bit awkward, but it may help the OP to understand some of the relevant methods of the JList object (and that is the objective, I think)